# Angular JS: Add class to element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing the next thing. I want to enter empty values in input its boundary highlighted (added new class 'warning'). I created the following code.

HTML:

```
`<body ng-app="TestPage">
 <form ng-controller="TestForm">
  <input ng-model="testinput" class="form-input" ng-class="testclass" type="text"/>
  <button ng-click="submitButton()">Click</button>
</form>
</body>`
```

JavaScript:

```
`angular.module('TestPage',[])
    .controller('TestForm', function($scope, $animate) {
         $scope.submitButton = function() {
             if (($scope.testinput == undefined) || ($scope.testinput == "")) {
                 $animate.addClass($scope.testclass, "warning");
             }
         };
    });`
```

But the use of the `addClass` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first parameter of addClass should be an element

Comment: But as to this element in the controller? Isn't using ng-class?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate)

the service $animate's addClass function has three parameters;

**First params is the element which the CSS classes will be applied to.**

Second params is the CSS class(es) that will be added (multiple classes are separated via spaces)

Third params is an optional collection of options/styles that will be applied to the element.

so your should try to do it :

html:

```
`<body ng-app="TestPage">
 <form ng-controller="TestForm">
  <input id="target_element" ng-model="testinput" class="form-input" ng-class="testclass" type="text"/>
  <button ng-click="submitButton()">Click</button>
</form>
</body>`
```

javascript:

```
`angular.module('TestPage',[])
    .controller('TestForm', function($scope, $animate) {
         $scope.submitButton = function() {
             if (($scope.testinput == undefined) || ($scope.testinput == "")) {
                 $animate.addClass(angular.element('#target_element'), "warning");
             }
         };
    });`
```

A better approach is to use the [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
module.directive('addClassBy',['$animate',function($animate){
    return function(scope,element){
        scope.$watch('testinput',function(newValue,oldValue){
            if(newValue === oldValue){return};
            if(newValue === undefined || newValue === ''){
                 $animate.addClass(element,'warning')
            }
        })
    }
}])
```

then html:

```
`<body ng-app="TestPage">
     <form ng-controller="TestForm">
      <input add-class-by ng-model="testinput" class="form-input" ng-class="testclass" type="text"/>
      <button ng-click="submitButton()">Click</button>
    </form>
    </body>`
```

Comment: Thanks for the option of angular.element. Dealt with him. About `directive`: your code does not work correctly, the class is changed only once.